Como avaliar/descobrir o consumo de RAM e processamento de uma aplicação NodeJS que está rodando?
Desenvolvi um sistema simples utilizando NodeJS, possui algumas rotas, renderiza páginas HTML com o EJS, efetua selects, inserts, deletes e updates em um banco de dados MariaDB (servidor este que estará na mesma maquina que a aplicação NodeJS).
Para fins de entendimento, a pasta do projeto contando a node_modules está com apenas 10mb, mas sem contar o banco de dados, que tem por volta de 5 tabelas e umas delas pode vir a ter 300+ linhas, as outras ficariam na casa de 10 a 50 linhas.
Pretendo colocar este projeto para rodar em uma VM, porém pelas minhas pesquisas de preço e recursos, as VMs disponveis do mercado (Azure, AWS, UOL Host, Locaweb), variam de 512mb de RAM e 1 vCPU, vão para 1GB ou 2GB de RAM com 2 vCPU e por volta de 10mb/s a 20mb/s e vai subindo a capacidade.
Minha dúvida é: Como eu poderia medir quanto de RAM e processamento meu projeto está consumindo atualmente no meu ambiente de desenvolvimento p/ que eu possa comprar a VM mais adequada? Ou um projeto nestes moldes que desenvolvi é claramente óbvio que uma VM de 512mb de RAM e 1 vCPU já atenderia (mesmo que houvesse mais de um processo ativo ao mesmo tempo do projeto)?

Já tentou https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processmemoryusage

Para obter o uso de memória use o process.memoryUsage(), exemplo:
const { memoryUsage } = require('node:process');

console.log(memoryUsage());


heapTotal: e heapUsed: referem-se ao uso de memória do V8.
external: refere-se ao uso de memória de objetos C++ vinculados a objetos JavaScript gerenciados pelo V8.
rss:, que significa Resident Set Size, é a quantidade de espaço ocupado no dispositivo de memória principal (que é um subconjunto da memória total alocada) para o processo, incluindo todos os objetos e códigos C++ e JavaScript.
arrayBuffers: refere-se à memória alocada para ArrayBuffers e SharedArrayBuffers, incluindo todos os Buffers Node.js. Isso também está incluído no valor externo. Quando o Node.js é usado como uma biblioteca incorporada, esse valor pode ser 0 porque as alocações para ArrayBuffers podem não ser rastreadas nesse caso.

Irá exibir algo semelhante a isso:
{
    rss: 4935680,
    heapTotal: 1826816,
    heapUsed: 650472,
    external: 49879,
    arrayBuffers: 9386
}

Se deseja obter somente o RSS (Resident Set Size), use o método process.memoryUsage.rss()
const { memoryUsage } = require('node:process');

console.log(memoryUsage.rss());
// retorna algo como: 35655680

Para obter o uso de CPU o process.cpuUsage(), que retorna o uso do tempo de CPU do usuário e do sistema do processo atual em um objeto com propriedades user: e system:, cujos valores são valores de microssegundos (milionésimo de segundo). Esses valores medem o tempo gasto no código do usuário e do sistema, respectivamente, e podem acabar sendo maiores do que o tempo decorrido real se vários núcleos de CPU estiverem executando trabalho para esse processo.
O resultado de uma chamada anterior para process.cpuUsage() pode ser passado como argumento para a função.
Um exemplo básico:
const { cpuUsage } = require('node:process');

const startUsage = cpuUsage();
// retorna algo como: { user: 38579, system: 6986 }

// gire a CPU por 500 milissegundos
const now = Date.now();
while (Date.now() - now < 500);

console.log(cpuUsage(startUsage));
// retorna algo como: { user: 514883, system: 11226 }

Em uma aplicação com diferentes callbacks é melhor criar uma chamada de tempos em tempos, por exemplo, de um em um segundo você compara o cpuUsage() com o valor anterior e envia ao callback, fora do contexto do resto da aplicação, como das rotas.

Nota: O uso dos métodos memoryUsage e cpuUsage não irá medir o consumo outras serviços, como banco de dados


Load Average
No Node.js também existe o método os.loadavg(), mas ele não atenderá o caso de medir a aplicação em si, pois ele se refere ao Load Average, que é uma informação que geralmente pode ser obtida em ambientes Unix-like e que refere-se à média total do número de processos em espera na lista de execução somado ao número de processos atualmente em execução, dentro do último período de 1, 5 e 15 minutos.
Mas se você estiver rodando a aplicação de forma isolada, como uma máquina virtual ou WSL, ela poderá atender a medições extras que você talvez precise, se a sua aplicação tiver outras operações, como banco de dados, como comandos de linha rodando internamente via node:child_process.

Nota: Este método não é compatível com Windows

Exemplo de uso:
const os = require('node:os');
const [one, five, fifteen] = os.loadavg();

console.log(`Carga média de 1 minuto: ${one}`);
console.log(`Carga média de 5 minutos: ${five}`);
console.log(`Carga média de 15 minutos: ${fifteen}`);

/*
retorna algo como:
Carga média de 1 minuto: 2.9326171875
Carga média de 5 minutos: 2.87890625
Carga média de 15 minutos: 2.87451171875
*/


Bibliotecas:
Se estiver usando o framework Express, consulte os pacotes disponíveis no npm:

https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=express%20monitor


Nota: É importante compreender que mesmo mensurando por conta própria, não há garantia de que todas operações em seus testes irão gastar exatamente o que será necessário no seu servidor, faça uma longa analise cuidadosa de diferentes dias e/ou se possível use ferramentas prontas, solicitando auxilio do suporte técnico da hospedagem que contratar
